# Stack Overflow in Spanish needs you!

Tags: discusión

I know I've mentioned it before here in [meta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/276/12), but I thought I'd bring it up again.

[Stack Overflow in Spanish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish?referrer=i2UNs-26fec9zlsUrCq6xg2) is nearing the end of its commitment phase.  It just needs a few more people to commit to the beta phase before it can go live!

If you are knowledgable in the programming field, and speak Spanish, I would encourage you to commit to this proposal.  Having another Spanish-language site on the SE network will no doubt help grow this site as well!

Comment: Thanks Flimzy I just committed. Didn't know there was such a proposal!

Comment: I'm on SO and here, but frankly I don't quite see the point of SO in Spanish. [related](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/7124/mathematics-in-spanish/8281#8281) Just my opinion, not to invite discussion, but to suggest that many others can fell like me.

Comment: Just a note to those who commit - we're definitely getting localized versions of SO out the door - but the work on localization required is massive, and will take a while to complete. Your enthusiasm is awesome, please don't get discouraged if you don't see any movement to public beta in months (or perhaps longer, but we're going as fast as we can).

Answer (score 6):

## The site has reached 100% commitment!

However, it's still not too late to [commit](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish?referrer=i2UNs-26fec9zlsUrCq6xg2) and help in the Private Beta.

As @TimPost has mentioned, it may be a while before the site actually goes live, as the SE developers are working on rolling new localization features.  So hang in there, and stay tuned.

Comment: Follow up note - internationalization is a development priority. However, the first sites to launch are likely the sites in languages where speakers are not very likely to be conversationally fluent in English, the interface will be translated to those first. I'll be keeping this, and a few others updated from time to time as work progresses.

Comment: Thanks for the update, @TimPost